# Private Method Confusion in Java

Tags: polymorphism, encapsulation

I am working on basic Java and this makes me confused about accessing private method in Java. In the following code, there is no compiling error as well as running time error

```
public class Base{
    private void foo() {
        System.out.println("In BaseClass.foo()");
    }
    void bar() {
        System.out.println("In BaseClass.bar()");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base po = new DerivedClass();
        po.foo();   // No compiling error here
        po.bar();
    }
}
class DerivedClass extends Base {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("In Derived.foo()");
    }
    void bar() {
        System.out.println("In Derived.bar()");
    }
}
```

But when I move the main method to the public JavaCertificate  class, it show error because of accessing private method foo

```
public class JavaCertificate {       
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Base po = new DerivedClass();
        po.foo();   // Now it shows compiling error
        po.bar();
    }
}
class Base{
        private void foo() {
            System.out.println("In BaseClass.foo()");
        }
        void bar() {
            System.out.println("In BaseClass.bar()");
        }

}
class DerivedClass extends Base {
    void foo() {
        System.out.println("In Derived.foo()");
    }
    void bar() {
        System.out.println("In Derived.bar()");
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain it for me. Thanks

Comment: What about this is confusing? That's the whole point of the `private` keyword.

Comment: The confusion here is you just basically change the position of main method to somewhere else and the encapsulation is broken. What is the point of private member when you can access to it from outside.

Comment: But you've just demonstrated that you *can't* access a private method "from outside"; a method can only call a `private` method if it's within the same class.

Comment: Does it count as "outside" if you create a new instance of a class in the main method and then call the private method of that class from its instance? I think the main method is just an entry point of application and it does not belong specifically to any class.

Comment: Re: "I think the main method is just an entry point of application and it does not belong specifically to any class": And what makes you think that?